# Comparing files in a directory

Tags: diff

Suppose I have x amount of files in a directory (where x = greater than 100) and I want to compare these files for differences. How can I accomplish this task? I am running an Ubuntu 18.04 machine. For the sake of this discussion, assume the said directory is /home/user1/music_list/ and one of the files in the directory is /home/user1/music_list/jazz1.txt.

Comment: Do you mean you want to compare them one to one (so thousands of comparisons) and see the differences? What sort of differences are you interested in? Which byte differ as in the output of `cmd -l`? Or which lines differ or are missing or have been added between the two files, possibly with context as in the `diff -u` output?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I am interested in the line by line content difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It does depend on whether the files are likely to be mainly identical. The presentation of thousands of comparisons is also utterly confusing, unless you can identify "reference versions", or some sequence of progressive modifications.

I once got tasked to resolve an issue with a push-out mechanism that had reliability issues. There were 160 servers that had 16,000 image files for various layers of power network sites, so 2.5 million files.

Basically, I let them vote for the most popular versions. I had each server checksum all its own files, and send me a list of checksum, date, size, name. I grouped and counted by checksum. Any file that was 100% consistent across the set was fine. Anything that agreed above 80% of cases showed up those servers that had missed an update. Anything below 20% was a failed delete, or a rogue test file. There were very few in the 20% to 80% range.

In my use case, it was also easy to detect image files that had been uploaded to different servers with the wrong name or path.

This kind of method might not solve your issue, but it can seriously reduce the number of detailed comparisons you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

To compare all regular files within `/some/dir` (recursively) one to one, you could do in `zsh`:

```
function {
  local fileA fileB
  for fileA do
    shift
    for fileB do
      diff -su $fileA $fileB
    done
  done
} /some/dir/**/*(ND.)
```

Here showing the difference in unified format with context with `-u` and reporting when files are identical with `-s` (non-standard).

But beware that with over 100 files, that will be thousands of one-to-one comparisons.

With GNU `diff`, adding the `--color=always` option to `diff` and passing the output of that anonymous function to `less -R` may make that output a bit more palatable.

The same with `bash` instead of `zsh` but assuming version 4.4 or above (for `readarray -d`) and the GNU implementations (or compatible) of the `find` and `sort` utilities (for their `-print0` and `-z` extensions):

```
(
  readarray -td '' files < <(
    find /some/dir/ -type f -print0 | sort -z)
  set -- "${files[@]}"
  for fileA do
    shift
    for fileB do
      diff -su "$fileA" "$fileB"
    done
  done
)
```

If there's a lot of duplication, you can reduce the number of comparisons by first indicating which files are identical, and then only pick one in each set of identical files to compare against the one file of other sets.

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -A set
files=(/some/dir/**/*(ND.))
for file in $files; do
  sum=$(sha1sum < $file) || continue
  # store the list of files having a given checksum NUL delimited
  # in an associative array
  set[$sum]+=$file$'\0'
done
sums=(${(k)set})
for sum1 in $sums; do
  shift 1 sums
  files1=(${(0)set[$sum1]}) # split on NUL
  (( $#files < 2 )) || print -r All of ${(j[, ])files1} are identical
  for sum2 in $sums; do
    files2=(${(0)set[$sum2]})
    diff -u $files1[1] $files2[1]
  done
done
```

(untested).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script.

I have included a `diff` or `comm` command depending on preferred output.

```bsh
for i in /home/user1/music_list/*.txt; do
        index_file="$i"
        echo "$(tput setaf 1)Comparing "$i" $(tput sgr 0)"
        for n in /home/user1/music_list/*.txt; do
                next_file="$n"
                echo "$(tput setaf 5)With "$n" $(tput sgr 0)"
                #comm -3 <(sort "$index_file") <(sort "$next_file")
                diff -s <(sort "$index_file") <(sort "$next_file")
                shift
        done
done
```

**Output with `comm`**

```
Comparing z.txt
With z1.txt
With z2.txt
1
        2
With z3.txt
1
        22
With z4.txt
1
        222
```

`comm` will print the name with no output when identical as can be noted with `z1.txt`

**Output with `diff`**

```
Comparing z.txt
With z1.txt
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
With z2.txt
1c1
< 1
---
> 2
With z3.txt
1c1
< 1
---
> 22
With z4.txt
1c1
< 1
---
> 222
```

Comment: That compares files twice though (*comparing a.txt with b.txt* and later *comparing b.txt with a.txt*).

Comment: And also (if I read it correctly) compares `a.txt` with `a.txt`. I would also have concerns about the sorts: (a) the overhead (b) the implication that the order of lines in a text file is irrelevant (c) reporting the temporary names.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the question above is improved by informing me that only one file in the directory, /home/user1/music_list/, in question is unique. To find which is the unique file, consider this answer and tell me what you think:

`$diff -r --from-file=/home/user1/music_list/jazz1.txt /home/user1/music_list/`

My thought is that I can just compare one of the files in the directory,./jazz.txt, to all the other files in the same directory, to see which is different from jazz.txt.